# how can we add bottomnavigationbar in Sliver App widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I want to Add this fixed **bottomNavigationbar** in Scrollable sliver App Widget, is there any way we can do it or any alternative way to do this

```
BottomNavigationBar(

        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
          title: Text('Deals'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          title: Text('Favourites'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.portrait),
          title: Text('Profile'),
        ),
      ],


 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly add the said `bottomNavigationBar` to the `SliverAppBar` using `NestedScrollView` and add `bottomNavigationBar` outside of it. Here's working code:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text("Sliver with bottomnavbar",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      )),
                  background: Image.network(
                    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Text"),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
            title: Text('Deals',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: Text('Favourites',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.portrait),
            title: Text('Profile',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Also, I need to add navigation routes in the bottom navigation icons, how can it be done?

for eg: Home icon should navigate to landing page,
deals icon should navigate to deals page and so on

Comment: Check this link (from Step 3) on how to add navigation routes to each nav bar item. https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-use-flutter-to-build-an-app-with-bottom-navigation

Comment: If your original question is answered, accept / upvote so that it'll be helpful for others as well.